# My answer was deleted but at the same time other similar answers were not, why?

Tags: discussion

My [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/743909/whatsapp-client-for-ubuntu-desktop-14-04) was deleted but other [answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/746304/how-can-i-use-whatsapp-web-on-ubuntu) on this site are not, why?? Not pointing a particular answer but several other answers like that. Why?? Why not some uniform and consistent standards?

If there are some users who just visits askubuntu to get the answers and not even mark it as accepted even if that is the potential answer(or close to the answer) that is working as disadvantage for few such answers.

Moreover I heard that SE is based on ElasticSearch so why not it simply pops up the answer(even when they are deleted)?

Answer (score 5):

Your answer was deleted because it didn't answer the question.

In the question you posted your answer to the problem is that OP is not able to download the client they paid for. They're asking how they could solve that issue, not for an alternative solution.

The other question you mention instead explicitly asks for how to get to use WhatsApp Web on Ubuntu, which the answer posted to it *does* address.

So, in short, they both suggest using whatsappweb.com, but they're not quite the same answer and anyway they've been posted to two different questions: such an answer answers the second question but not the first one (the one you posted your answer to).

Comment: Not sure but i believe OP was okay with the answer(Wow, thanks for the sass) Don't know what sass means...but still the answer was deleted...there are many answers which are not the exact answer but a potential or alternate solution. Don't you think that rather than paying for whatsapp client(whatsapp itself is free on smartphones now) providing a whatsapp web(https://web.whatsapp.com/) was a much better solution???

Comment: @Ashu Thanking someone for a sass is a sarcastic way of telling them they've been impudent. It's not about what I think, it's about whay they ask. They paid for the client already and their question is about how to download it. While many times it's acceptable to provide an alternative solution I'd say that's not the case at all.